# SPA pre-rendering in Asp.net core?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, single-page-application, prerender

How do i implement prerenderio in asp.net core, for angular spa. Or is there any way that asp.net core has introduced to do this. Actually i am migrating my old asp.net to asp.net core.

Comment: what do you need in "pre-render"?  KEep in mind that Webforms and MVC are two different paradigms. You have the REquest->Response pipeline, as opposed to the old event-driven paradigm of Webforms.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Nothing in the questions points towards webforms or mvc

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I mean to say asp.net mvc to asp.net core, and i havent seen that webform till now..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a package offered by Microsoft which allows to pre-render/execute Nodejs/JavaScript on the server side, commonly known under "JavaScriptServices". You can find it on the [ASP.NET team's GitHub repository](http://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices).

There are different packages that build up on different packages. The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices` is the base package, usually used for people who implement their own server-sided execution based on NodeJS. Then there is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices` which is based on `NodeServices` and tailored for single plage applications (SPAs) and finally there is a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices` package which provides Angular specific extensions and is based on `SpaServices`.

On the GitHub you can find examples, for example the [MusicStore SPA](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/samples/angular/MusicStore) with server-side rendering.

Comment: Thanks for providing information, i was unsure that which was the correct .I will try to follow up your information.